# Custom Font in iPad Doesnt work

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

In my Application i am using Custom font. i copied my font.ttf file in my project directory and i used following code to set custom font to a label.

```
[input setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"My Font" size: input.font.pointSize]]
```

The problem is it works perfect in iPhone 4.2 simulator but it in iPad 4.2 simulator it just Displays Default Font. How to resolve this?

Comment: did you open the font file in finder and use the full name of the font instead of the filename (eg. "My Custom Font" instead of "my_custom_font.ttf")

Comment: I am using "My Font Name" in info.plist file

Comment: in info.plist you should use "my_custom_font.ttf" under UIAppFonts key, but in code you should use [UIFont fontWithName:"My Custom Font"]
thats the confusing part for me

Comment: I did exactly what you are saying !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is use for the custom font.

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 240, 40)];
[label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Grinched" size:24]];
[label1 setText:@"Grinched Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 240, 40)];
[label2 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Energon" size:18]];
[label2 setText:@"Energon Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label2];
```

If you want shows the tutorial for that [you visits the refrence link here](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/25/load-and-access-custom-fonts/)

May this code help for development.

Happy codeing

Thanks and Regards
@samuel

Answer (score 0):

If You Want To Use Custom-Font..Folow This Steps...

1. Add the font files to your resource files
2. Edit your `Info.plist`: Add a new entry with the key `Fonts provided by application`.
3. For each of your files, add the file name to this array

On the example below, I've added the font "DejaVu Sans Mono":

[image: Info.plist: adding custom fonts]

In your application you can the use

```
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 240, 50)];

    [label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"DejaVuSansMono-Bold" size:14.f]];
```

Or if you want to use it in html/css, just use `font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono;`

**Note:** this is available in iOS 3.2 and later.